# How to detect MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN in service Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

I am running a background service to detect MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN in Android 5.0. I used bellow code and it can detect my touch event but i cannot touch other apps. How can I fix it? If you have a better solution, please give me. Thank all.

```
public class TouchServiceListener extends Service implements OnTouchListener {
    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    // linear layout will use to detect touch event
    private LinearLayout touchLayout;   

     @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        touchLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            // set layout width 30 px and height is equal to full screen
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            touchLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
            // set color if you want layout visible on screen
            touchLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            // set on touch listener
            touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

            // fetch window manager object
            mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            // set layout parameter of window manager
            WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // width of layout 30 px
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // height is equal to full screen
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, // Type Ohone, These are non-application windows providing user interaction with the phone (in particular incoming calls).
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, // this window won't ever get key input focus
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            mParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
            Log.i(TAG, "add View");

            mWindowManager.addView(touchLayout, mParams);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {        
        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP|motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Touch me");
        }
        return true;
    }
 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }
 }
```

Manifest

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all make your Layout according to overlay.you are setting width and height match_parent which is cover whole screen so that you are not accessing application which is outside of your application.

```
 package anew.mikka.myapplication;

    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class max extends Service implements View.OnTouchListener {
        Button mButton;
        @Override
        public IBinder
        onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            //mView = new HUDView(this);
            mButton = new Button(this);
            mButton.setText("Overlay button");
            mButton.setOnTouchListener(this);

            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;
            params.setTitle("Load Average");
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.addView(mButton, params);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if(mButton != null)
            {
                ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mButton);
                mButton = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Overlay button event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }


    }
```

Comment: I tried it before. But it cannot press any apps when i used above code. Could you try?

Comment: I tried this code after that post here.If you want to access another application control then its not possible.

Comment: Thank you. I have tested it. Sorry for the delay. Your code is worked. However, it showed a button on my screen. I tried to make it invisible, but the touch will not show when I make it invisible.

Comment: I fixed it, I set  `mButton = new Button(this);
        mButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1, 1));` and `WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                1,
                1,`

Comment: How to handle type of touches inside `onTouch()`